# Alternative for ‘gute Besserung’?

Tags: german-to-english, phrase-request

Can *gute Besserung* be said for someone who’s fighting cancer? Or is it just for illnesses that are not life-threatening such as flu?

Does an acceptable alternative to *gute Besserung* exist for life-threatening illnesses?

Comment: Maybe you can say 'Ich wünsche dir viel Kraft'

Comment: Wieso willst Du nicht *gute Besserung* sagen?

Comment: @userunknown sorry I write in English but I understand spoken and writen German. Because I feel `gute Besserung` is too soft for something like cancer.

Comment: Gute Besserung is a wish, that the person will have a better condition than what they have at the moment. I think it is not soft or hard. It is just a wish.

Comment: @Tom-Oliver Heidel, write this as an answer and you'll get +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sense of »Halt die Ohren steif!« you could say

> Lass dich nicht kleinkriegen!

or

> Lass dich nicht unterkriegen!

meaning »don't lose heart«.

Answer (score 2):

The wish “Gute Besserung” should only be used for ills that have realistic probability of going away. Or at least become better in the foreseeable future (usually a few days or weeks).

It should not be used for chronic diseases. Otherwise it can easily sound sarcastic, such as someone jumping from a cliff and you wish them a nice flight.

Comment: This is not a full answer for my question as I also need an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could say "Gute Genesung". Means the same.

Comment: Eine ausführlichere Antwort wäre wünschenswert. Vor allem, da nicht nach Synonymen gefragt ist, sondern nach der Angemessenheit des Ausdrucks.